# Restart ghost blog running inside Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, ghost

I'm using the [Official Ghost Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ghost/), and have ghost running without a problem.

I am developing a theme locally on the host, which is mounted as a volume inside the container. As with any running ghost instance, in order to see the theme changes, I need to stop and restart ghost.

Normally this would simply mean ending the Node process and running `npm start` again. But inside the official Docker image, this is not an option. If I try and run `npm start`, I'm told:

`ERROR: (EADDRINUSE) Cannot start Ghost.`

which makes sense, as the port ***is*** already in use.

I've tried manually killing the processes with no success. If I kill the node process with

`kill -9 *node process ID*`

The container crashes out. I've tried also killing the npm process, but this never seems to go down.

Any ideas?

Comment: You would normally just kill and restart the container.  Rather than editing files *inside* the container, consider making the configuration files available to the container as a host volume using the `-v` option.

Comment: That is precisely what i'm doing - as mentioned above: _"I am developing a theme locally on the host, which is mounted as a volume inside the container"._

Comment: Killing and restarting the container doesn't necessarily restart the node process inside the container?

Comment: Killing the container will kill any processes started by that container.

Comment: True, but it doesn't solve the problem. I'm mounting the volume precisely so I don't have to keep stopping/starting containers, but it's not clear how to stop/restart the node ghost process once it's running inside the container.

Comment: In general, a container is running a single process; you should not need to "enter" a container in most cases (don't see them as "virtual machines", see them as the "process itself"). `docker restart <mycontainer>` should restart ghost (and the container)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not clear why you are differentiating between "stopping/starting the container" and "stopping/starting the ghost process".  These two things should be functionally identical in most cases.

Comment: I appreciate all the input but this is all still avoiding the actual question. I am quite clear about docker container life cycles - this question is not really about docker, it's about the docker implementation of ghost. Without any docker specifics, I'm simply trying to understand how, within this context, the ghost process is started and stopped.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I deploy my ghost blog in docker:

`docker run --name some-blog -d -p 80:2368 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com -v /home/ghost/blogfiles/:/var/lib/ghost --restart unless-stopped ghost`

The `--restart unless-stopped` is useful for when docker containers randomly crash. It will automatically restart them.

Listing your docker containers by doing a `docker ps` you should get something like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
11d2517205de        ghost                    "/entrypoint.sh npm s"   2 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80->2368/tcp                             some-blog
```

To restart the docker container you can either do `docker stop [container id]` and `docker start [container id]` or simply `docker restart [container id]`.